# Elixir Phoenix serve Javascript from /priv/static

Tags: javascript, jquery, elixir, phoenix-framework, esbuild

I am currently fighting esbuild in my phoenix project. I have a heex template on which I want to use Trumbowyg as a text editor. First I tried to import the javascript file via vendoring it and doing `import trumbowyg from '../vendor/trumbowyg.min.js` in `app.js`.

I thought this would work because it did for AlpineJs. But it didn't. It complained about missing jQuery. So I vendored jQuery the same way: `import {jQuery, $} from '../vendor/jquery.min.js`. But no success. Same error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Then I had the idea to fix it via importing the scripts in the template withing `<script>` tags. SO i just threw the two js files into the /priv/static/assets/ folder. This worked in development with the following tags:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src={Routes.static_path(@conn, "/assets/jquery.min.js")}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={Routes.static_path(@conn, "/assets/trumbowyg.min.js")}></script>
```

But this stopped working in production (I use the docker deploy method). Then I tried using some kind of `Plug.Static` implementation but I did not get it to work.

So my question now is: How can I make those scripts load in a production environment? Even better would be to know how to configure esbuild to use deploy the script files correctly. I don't know what to change, because my AlpineJs import is working fine.

```js
import "phoenix_html"
// Establish Phoenix Socket and LiveView configuration.
import {Socket} from "phoenix"
import {LiveSocket} from "phoenix_live_view"
import topbar from "../vendor/topbar"

import Alpine from "../vendor/alpine.min"

window.Alpine = Alpine;



let csrfToken = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content")
let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live", Socket, {
    params: {_csrf_token: csrfToken},
    dom: {
      onBeforeElUpdated(from, to) {
        if (from._x_dataStack) {
          window.Alpine.clone(from, to)
        }
      }
    }
  })

// Show progress bar on live navigation and form submits
topbar.config({barColors: {0: "#29d"}, shadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)"})
window.addEventListener("phx:page-loading-start", info => topbar.show())
window.addEventListener("phx:page-loading-stop", info => topbar.hide())

// connect if there are any LiveViews on the page
liveSocket.connect()

// expose liveSocket on window for web console debug logs and latency simulation:
// >> liveSocket.enableDebug()
// >> liveSocket.enableLatencySim(1000)  // enabled for duration of browser session
// >> liveSocket.disableLatencySim()
window.liveSocket = liveSocket
```

That's the content of my app.js file. But like I said, adding: `import trumbowyg from '../vendor/trumbowyg.min.js` or `import {jQuery, $} from '../vendor/jquery.min.js` gets me errors like `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

Every help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's the best way of doing things in Phoenix but what I do is to use `phx-hook` for these purposes.
Set up a new JS hook with something like:

```
import YourJSObject from 'your-lib'
Trumbowyg = {
    mounted() {
        ....
    },
    updated(){ 
        ....
     }
}
export default Trumbowyg;
```

import it in your `app.js` and add it your hooks:

```
let Hooks = { ..., Trumbowyg, ...  }
...
let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live", Socket, {params: {_csrf_token: csrfToken}, hooks: Hooks})
```

Once all this is set up you add it to your live component root element with `phx-hook`

```
<div id="some-id" class="some-classes" phx-hook="Trumbowyg">
```

and your imported JS should work on that component.

Hope that helps.